# Protecting a URL with a Query Parameter when Using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, urlencode

I'm having a really hard time sending an automated email (with Google Apps Script) that includes a URL that contains query parameter.

### Expected Behavior

Google Apps Script (specifically, the `Gmail` service) sends an email, and part of the email body contains a URL with a query parameter. The URL will look something like this:
http://my.app/products?id=Bz9n7PJLg8hufTj11gMF

### Observed Behavior

The `Gmail` service seems to be stripping out the `=` from my URL. So, the body of the email ends up looking like this:
...
**http://my.app/products?idBz9n7PJLg8hufTj11gMF**
...

Obviously, that link won't work.

I've checked other questions here on SO, and I've tried working with the [base encoding](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#base64Encode(Byte)) tools from the GAS Utilities service, as well as working with the `encodeURI()` JavaScript method. No luck so far.

### Email-sending Code

```
    //////// GENERATING MESSAGE FROM ID ////////////
    // Gets message from ID
    var id = Gmail.Users.Drafts.get('me', 'r-1006091711303067868').message.id
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id)
    var template = message.getRawContent()
    
    // Replaces template variables with custom ones for the user using RegExes
    let listingUrl = 'http://my.app/products?id=xyz'
    let creatorEmail = 'hello@gmail.com'
    let creatorUsername = 'Sam'
    template = template.replace(/templates@my.app/g, creatorEmail)
    template = template.replace(/firstName/g, creatorUsername)
    //** Below is the string that gets modified and broken **//
    template = template.replace(/listingUrl/g, listingUrl)
    
    // Creates the new message
    var message = Gmail.newMessage()
    var encodedMsg = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(template)
    message.raw = encodedMsg
    
    // Sends it
    Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, "me", Utilities.newBlob(template, "message/rfc822"))
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Added the email-sending code sample

Comment: `listingUrl` declaration is not included. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I've added them.

Comment: @DavisJones I'm not able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @DavisJones Pinpoint the line where `=` is missing. Is it after `template = template.replace(/listingUrl/g, listingUrl)` or
    after
    `message.raw = encodedMsg` or after `Utilities.newBlob(template, "message/rfc822")`. Decode it back to check if necessary

Comment: In my environment, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue using your script.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this. @TheMaster The `=` stays in the code all the way until the message is sent. The mail in the Gmail UI doesn't display the `=` (incidentally, neither does the location that it links to), *however*, if you check out `⋮ > Show original` from the UI, you can see that the `=` is in fact there for the text part, but has been removed in the html part. Logging `Utilities.newBlob(template, "message/rfc822").getDataAsString()` does however display it with the `=`. Looks buggy to me. [My test message](https://imgur.com/a/k5E36jc)

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Great!  Probably irrelevant, but Maybe it has something to do with rfc? May be op should try `rfc2822`

Comment: @TheMaster Tried `rfc2822` as well but results in the same missing `=`. Going to try and replicate this with the python library to see if this is an issue with the API or the GAS wrapper.

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo I think that it is a good comment. I couldn't notice that the situation occurs at the HTML body. In the case of text body, `http://my.app/products?id=xyz` can be correctly seen. So I thought that OP's situation cannot be replicated. When HTML body is used, I think that to modify from `http://my.app/products?id=xyz` to `http://my.app/products?id&#61;xyz` might be a workaround. In this case, `Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, "me");` can be also used.

Comment: @Tanaike Replacing the `=` with `&#61;` absolutely works. I am not sure, however, if simpler mail applications that do not render html will display this directly as `&#61;` instead of rendering the `=`. Additionally, I also can not get this to replicate using the python library so I think it's an encoding issue in the GAS wrapper somewhere.

Comment: @Tanaike your solution of replacing `=` with `&#61;` totally works. Thanks!

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo I apologize for my late replying. I noticed your replying now. In my email client, both `?id=xyz` and `?id&#61;xyz` can be seen as `?id=xyz` even when it's HTML body. I could replicate the issue by logging in to Gmail using Chrome. Furthermore, in this case, when my email client gets this email, the correct query parameter can be seen. From this situation, when `=` is replaced with `&#61;`, I thought that it can be used for both situation. But I also think that about this issue, to know the OP's situation for replicating the issue is important as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex-based Solution

With the help of [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783673/protecting-a-url-with-a-query-parameter-when-using-google-apps-script/63814601#comment112937834_63783673) and [Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783673/protecting-a-url-with-a-query-parameter-when-using-google-apps-script/63814601#comment112802622_63783673), the solution that ended up working for me was to replace `=` with `&#61;` by using a little `.replace()` like this:
`listingUrl = listingUrl.replace(/=/, '&#61;')`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was that the path portion of the URL must end with a forward slash `/`, before the query parameters.

```
https://example.com/this/is/a/path/?param=123
```